# Postgresql query array of objects in JSONB field filter Specific Object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-11

```
CREATE TABLE company (id SERIAL, companyJson JSONB);
CREATE INDEX comapny_gin_idx ON company USING gin (companyJson);

INSERT INTO company (id, companyJson) 
  VALUES (1, '[{"name": "t", "company": "company1"}]');

INSERT INTO company (id, companyJson) 
  VALUES (2, '[{"name": "b", "company":"company2"}, {"name": "b", "company":"company3"}]');


 SELECT * FROM company WHERE companyJson @> '[{"company": "company2" , "name": "b"}]';
```

The output of the above program is

```
2   [{"name": "b", "company": "company2"}, {"name": "b", "company": "company3"}]
```

Is there anyway to return {"name": "b", "company": "company2"} instead whole row.

Comment: version is PostgreSQL 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of unnesting the array and the return the element from that:

```
SELECT x.j
FROM company c
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(c.companyjson) as x(j)
where x.j = '{"company": "company2" , "name": "b"}'
```

Comment: Does this uses indexing which i have created on the table. Since one record may contain 5000 array of json objects.

Comment: @Balu: no I don't think so, but you can see for yourself by using `explain (analyze) select ..`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly return the first component through `companyJson -> 0` which contains `->` operand returning the first component by argument zero :

```
 SELECT companyJson -> 0 as companyJson
   FROM company 
  WHERE companyJson @> '[{"company": "company2" , "name": "b"}]';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cbc738fd75f6d1750e07611da1a51613)</kbd>